# Conditional formatting based on cell above

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Given these cell values in Excel (say column A):

```
420
420
480
444
445
```

If the number above is lower, I want the cell to be highlighted green. If it remains equal, I want the cell highlighted yellow. If the number above is higher, I want the cell highlighted red. In other words; the cells should be formatted (blank), yellow, green, red, green (respectively).

I am having a lot of trouble applying/finding the correct conditional formatting 'rule' here. Anyone that can help me? Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is 3 conditional formatting rules.

`=A2=A1`

`=A2<A1`

`=A1<A2`

Set the conditional formatting up in cell `A2` and then click on the cell, click on the format painter, and drag it down.

[image: Example]